# Hierarchical CLH lock behaviour

Tags: multiprocessor

Could anyone explain how does a HCLH lock handles the new nodes that are created in the local cluster after the Cluster Master has merged the local queue into the global queue?

Answer (score 0):

Once the local queue is merged on to the global queue, the cluster master sets the tailWhenSpliced field to true. The new local node that is added will know that it is the cluster master when it checks the predecessor's tailWhenSpliced flag. I have cut the long answer short.

Comment: an addition. The cluster master sets the `tailWhenSpliced` field of the tail node of local queue to `true`